Smooth vs. topological: foliation into closures of orbits
Consider a (partial) map $f\colon X → X$ and the maximal closures of orbits of $f$ (i.e., closures of orbits which are not contained in larger closures of orbits).  Assume that $X$ is foliated into such “orbital subsets” as a topological space.  Are there simple examples of smooth $f$ for which such a foliation is not smooth at generic points?
Variant: $f$ corresponding to Poincaré first recurrence map for a smooth vector field.  Or yet more generally: replace $f$ by the “recurrence” equivalence relation on a transversal to a leaf of a foliation.

Is $X$ a smooth manifold and $f: X\to X$ a smooth map? What does "partial" exactly mean? What do you mean by "at generic points?" Do you mean that there is an open and dense subset $U\subset X$ such that your topological foliation restricts to a smooth foliation on $U$?

@MoisheKohan: Yes. A map $U → X$ with $U⊆X$ (think of Poincaré map). Yes.
